# textDecoration:none doesn't wanna work on cssText when I try to change it using js

Tags: javascript, css

textDecoration:none doesn't wanna work on cssText when I try to change it using js

```
document.querySelectorAll("nav > *").forEach(function (e) {
      e.style.cssText = " textDecoration:none ;color: #000";
    });
```

Comment: only the color property works

Comment: The property should be called `text-decoration` I think

Comment: yeah too much js made me right every thing in camel case style

Answer (score 2):

CSS properties use dashes to separate words like this: `text-decoration`. In JavaScript, these same properties are referenced in camelCase instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

There are two solutions:

Either use the dashed-out property name, as is correct in CSS:

```js
e.style.cssText = "text-decoration: none; color: #000;";
```

or reference the properties in JavaScript:

```js
e.style.textDecoration = "none";
e.style.color = "#000";
```

Comment: Yeah I just realized my mistake and how stupid it made me look i was about to delete the qst thank you for your answer though